# Talking to Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Online using PHP & Soap

Tags: php, soap, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, microsoft-dynamics

Hi does anyone know of a simple example with interfacing with microsoft dynamics using php and SOAP. I've done a bit of reading around and it looks like they have recently changed their authentication headers?
Examples such as this one are out of date:
http://mscrmtools.blogspot.pt/2012/08/php-to-crm-online-easy-way-to-do.html

Does anyone have any idea how to get this to work?

Thank you!

Matt

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this article?

[Use the WSDL Endpoint for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 and Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509052.aspx).

Not that I've used it myself, but the article suggests using the WSDL when you are using non .net languages.

> While the most common style of development for Microsoft Dynamics CRM
>   2011 and Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online is using the SOAP endpoint with
>   early or late bound types, there are situations where you wish to use
>   the Web Services Description Language (WSDL) endpoint directly. This
>   is a light-weight endpoint that can be used from non-.NET languages.

Comment: did you checked the comments over there, code is not supported for Office 365.

Comment: What office 365 got to do with this question?

Answer (score 1):

There is various samples out there these days some of which successfully connect to CRM Online using SOAP and the Office 365 authentication system.

If you are still looking for a solution then I have started documenting my solution here.
http://crmtroubleshoot.blogspot.com.au/2013/07/dynamics-crm-2011-php-and-soap-using.html

Basically you need to authenticate against https://login.microsoftonline.com/RST2.srf which returns the required tokens for Office 365 authentication.